# Как при выборе страны сделать чтобы менялся флаг?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы при выборе страны менялся флаг ?

```js
var numberSelect = $('.number-select__list');
var numberSelectFlag = $('.number-select__flag');
var citiesDropdown = $('.cities-dropdown__menu');
numberSelectFlag.click(function(list) {
  numberSelect.slideToggle('fast');
  list.stopPropagation();
});

if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
  numberSelectFlag.click(function() {
    citiesDropdown.slideUp('fast');
  });
}

$(document).on('click', '.number-select__item', function() {
  let country = $(this).find('.number-select__country-name').text();
  let code = $(this).find('.number-select__dial-code').text();

  $('.number-select__selected-dial-code').text(`${code} (${country})`);
  numberSelect.slideToggle('fast');
});

$(document).click(function() {
  numberSelect.slideUp('fast');
});
```

```css
.number-select__flag {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 274px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*margin-left: 12px;*/
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #383839;
  background-image: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFFFFF url(../svg/phone-search-arrow.svg) no-repeat 95.4% 51%;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.number-select__list {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  width: 302px;
  max-height: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-right: 25px;
  /*margin-left: 25px;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cities-dropdown__menu {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  width: 302px;
  max-height: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-right: 25px;
  /*margin-left: 25px;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cities-dropdown__menu li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 17px;
}

.cities-dropdown__menu li:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.number-select__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.number-select__dial-code {
  color: #A0A0A0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.number-select__country-name {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: #383839;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.number-select__selected-dial-code {
  padding-top: 1px;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.number-select__output {
  display: flex;
}

.number-select__us {
  background-image: url('https://solvulate.com/wp-content/themes/solvulate/assets/images/svg/flag/flag-united-states-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.number-select__uk {
  background-image: url('https://solvulate.com/wp-content/themes/solvulate/assets/images/svg/flag/flag-united-kingdom-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.number-select__ar {
  background-image: url('https://solvulate.com/wp-content/themes/solvulate/assets/images/svg/flag/flag-argentina-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.number-select__au {
  background-image: url('https://solvulate.com/wp-content/themes/solvulate/assets/images/svg/flag/flag-australia-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number-area">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 number number-box">
    <div class="number-search">
      <div class="number-dropdown">
        <div class="number-select">
          <div class="number-select__flag">
            <div class="number-select__output">
              <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__us"></div>
              <div class="number-select__selected-dial-code">+1 (United States)</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="number-select__list">
            <li class="number-select__item" id="GB">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__uk">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">United Kingdom</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+44</span>
            </li>
            <li class="number-select__item" id="US">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__us">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">United States</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+1</span>
            </li>
            <li class="number-select__item" id="AR">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__ar">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">Argentina</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+54</span>
            </li>
            <li class="number-select__item" id="AU">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__au">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">Australia</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+61</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял у вас одинаковые классы для отображения флагов, если они всегда будут иметь одинаковый набор классов, то пу сути вам надо добавить всего 1 строчку `numberSelectFlagIco.attr('class', target.find('.number-select__wraps').attr('class'));`. Просто забрать все классы флага у нажатого и поставить вместо классов у уже выбранного:

```js
var numberSelect = $('.number-select__list');
var numberSelectFlag = $('.number-select__flag');
var numberSelectFlagIco = $('.number-select__flag .number-select__wraps');
var citiesDropdown = $('.cities-dropdown__menu');
numberSelectFlag.click(function(list) {
  numberSelect.slideToggle('fast');
  list.stopPropagation();
});

if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
  numberSelectFlag.click(function() {
    citiesDropdown.slideUp('fast');
  });
}

$(document).on('click', '.number-select__item', function() {
  const target = $(this);
  let country = target.find('.number-select__country-name').text();
  let code = target.find('.number-select__dial-code').text();
  
  numberSelectFlagIco.attr('class', target.find('.number-select__wraps').attr('class'));

  $('.number-select__selected-dial-code').text(`${code} (${country})`);
  numberSelect.slideToggle('fast');
});

$(document).click(function() {
  numberSelect.slideUp('fast');
});
```

```css
.number-select__flag {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 274px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*margin-left: 12px;*/
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #383839;
  background-image: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFFFFF url(../svg/phone-search-arrow.svg) no-repeat 95.4% 51%;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.number-select__list {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  width: 302px;
  max-height: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-right: 25px;
  /*margin-left: 25px;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cities-dropdown__menu {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  width: 302px;
  max-height: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-right: 25px;
  /*margin-left: 25px;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cities-dropdown__menu li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 17px;
}

.cities-dropdown__menu li:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.number-select__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.number-select__dial-code {
  color: #A0A0A0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.number-select__country-name {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: #383839;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.number-select__selected-dial-code {
  padding-top: 1px;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.number-select__output {
  display: flex;
}

.number-select__us {
   background-image: url('https://solvulate.com/wp-content/themes/solvulate/assets/images/svg/flag/flag-united-states-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.number-select__uk {
  background-image: url('https://solvulate.com/wp-content/themes/solvulate/assets/images/svg/flag/flag-united-kingdom-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.number-select__ar {
  background-image: url('https://solvulate.com/wp-content/themes/solvulate/assets/images/svg/flag/flag-argentina-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.number-select__au {
  background-image: url('https://solvulate.com/wp-content/themes/solvulate/assets/images/svg/flag/flag-australia-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number-area">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 number number-box">
    <div class="number-search">
      <div class="number-dropdown">
        <div class="number-select">
          <div class="number-select__flag">
            <div class="number-select__output">
              <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__us"></div>
              <div class="number-select__selected-dial-code">+1 (United States)</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="number-select__list">
            <li class="number-select__item" id="GB">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__uk">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">United Kingdom</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+44</span>
            </li>
            <li class="number-select__item" id="US">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__us">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">United States</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+1</span>
            </li>
            <li class="number-select__item" id="AR">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__ar">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">Argentina</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+54</span>
            </li>
            <li class="number-select__item" id="AU">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__au">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">Australia</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+61</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: @gucci Всё равно эти изменения вам не помогут в целях безопасности, т.к. вся история изменений хранится на сайте. Даже удаление вопроса не поможет, т.к. удалённые вопросы тоже видны всем у кого большой рейтинг, модераторам и персоналу SO. Разве что немного сузится круг людей :)

Comment: А в индексе в google будет видны старые ссылки или новые ?

Comment: @Gucci Нуууу, там я не думаю что код индексируется. Но это уже мои догадки, не могу вам дать точный ответ

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо вам большое и хорошего дня.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435794/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-sub-menu-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2-2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-wp можете пожалуйста еще одобрить вот этот вопрос я убрал href. Очень был бы благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант в лоб, которое заменяет атрубут `class` у блока с флагом на `number-select__wraps number-select__` + ID выбранного "option".

```js
var numberSelect = $('.number-select__list');
var numberSelectFlag = $('.number-select__flag');
var citiesDropdown = $('.cities-dropdown__menu');
numberSelectFlag.click(function(list) {
  numberSelect.slideToggle('fast');
  list.stopPropagation();
});

if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
  numberSelectFlag.click(function() {
    citiesDropdown.slideUp('fast');
  });
}

$(document).on('click', '.number-select__item', function() {
  let country = $(this).find('.number-select__country-name').text();
  let code = $(this).find('.number-select__dial-code').text();

  let flag = $('.number-select__output .number-select__wraps');
  flag.attr('class', 'number-select__wraps number-select__'+$(this).attr('id').toLowerCase());
  
  $('.number-select__selected-dial-code').text(`${code} (${country})`);
  numberSelect.slideToggle('fast');
});

$(document).click(function() {
  numberSelect.slideUp('fast');
});
```

```css
.number-select__flag {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 274px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*margin-left: 12px;*/
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #383839;
  background-image: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFFFFF url(../svg/phone-search-arrow.svg) no-repeat 95.4% 51%;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.number-select__list {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  width: 302px;
  max-height: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-right: 25px;
  /*margin-left: 25px;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cities-dropdown__menu {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  width: 302px;
  max-height: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-right: 25px;
  /*margin-left: 25px;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cities-dropdown__menu li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 17px;
}

.cities-dropdown__menu li:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.number-select__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.number-select__dial-code {
  color: #A0A0A0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.number-select__country-name {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: #383839;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.number-select__selected-dial-code {
  padding-top: 1px;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.number-select__output {
  display: flex;
}

.number-select__us {
  background-image: url('https://dialics-site.intertech.dev/wp-content/themes/dialics/assets/svg/flag/flag-united-states-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.number-select__uk {
  background-image: url('https://dialics-site.intertech.dev/wp-content/themes/dialics/assets/svg/flag/flag-united-kingdom-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.number-select__ar {
  background-image: url('https://dialics-site.intertech.dev/wp-content/themes/dialics/assets/svg/flag/flag-argentina-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.number-select__au {
  background-image: url('https://dialics-site.intertech.dev/wp-content/themes/dialics/assets/svg/flag/flag-australia-min.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="number-area">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 number number-box">
    <div class="number-search">
      <div class="number-dropdown">
        <div class="number-select">
          <div class="number-select__flag">
            <div class="number-select__output">
              <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__us"></div>
              <div class="number-select__selected-dial-code">+1 (United States)</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="number-select__list">
            <li class="number-select__item" id="UK">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__uk">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">United Kingdom</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+44</span>
            </li>
            <li class="number-select__item" id="US">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__us">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">United States</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+1</span>
            </li>
            <li class="number-select__item" id="AR">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__ar">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">Argentina</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+54</span>
            </li>
            <li class="number-select__item" id="AU">
              <div class="number-select__flag-box">
                <div class="number-select__wraps number-select__au">
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="number-select__country-name">Australia</span>
              <span class="number-select__dial-code">+61</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Пример

```html
<form action="#" class="form">
  <div class="form__control">
    <input type="tel" id="phone">
  </div>
</form>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@18.2.1/build/css/intlTelInput.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@18.2.1/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const input = document.querySelector("#phone");
  window.intlTelInput(input, {
    preferredCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ar', 'au'],
    //onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ar', 'au'],
    utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@18.2.1/build/js/utils.js",
  });
</script>
```